# Shell scripting: How does escape sequence characters behave while retrieving value of variable with escape sequence in it?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

I have test.sh as shown below. When I run it like ./test.sh from bash shell, I get output as shown below.

test.sh

```
operator="\*"
echo $operator
expr 5 $operator 1
expr 5 \* 2
```

output

```
\*
expr: syntax error
10
```

I am not understanding why does it give syntax error for the third statement while fourth statement is working as expected.
If expr is only getting * as second argument in third statement, how does echo output \*?

Comment: Look at the output of your commands after you set `set -x` and you'll see what the commands get to see.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW.

Comment: BTW, note that it isn't good form to use `expr` at all. This command was needed back in the 1970s, when shells didn't have built-in math, but `$(( 5 * 2 ))` has been a mandatory part of the POSIX sh standard since 1991; taking advantage of this is *far* more efficient than running an external command (like `expr`) to do math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final stage of shell expansions in bash is [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal):

> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the
>   characters ‘`\`’, ‘`'`’, and ‘`"`’ that did not result from one of the
>   above expansions are removed.

The "above expansions" here being parameter (variable) expansion, command substitution, etc.

In `expr 5 \* 2`, the `\` will be removed by bash as part of quote removal, since it is not a result of variable (or other) expansions. So here, the argument that `expr` gets is `*`, after the removal of `\`.

In `expr 5 $operator 1` and `echo $operator`, the `\`  **will not** be removed, since it's a result of variable expansion. So in both of these commands, the argument that `echo` and `expr` get is `\*`, without the `\` being removed.

---

The best way here is to use quotes consistently:

```
operator="*"

echo "$operator"
expr 5 "$operator" 2
```

Otherwise, `\*` might still be subject to field splitting, if `IFS` happened to be set to something weird:

```
bash-4.4$ foo='\*'
bash-4.4$ echo $foo
\*
bash-4.4$ IFS='*'
bash-4.4$ echo $foo
\
bash-4.4$ echo "$foo"
\*
```

Comment: Thanks @muru for the quick response. It helped!